# re-order associative array based on reference associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have two associative arrays

```
$reference = array(
  'type_drink' => 'value', 
  'type_plate' => 'value', 
  'type_fork' => 'value', 
  'non_type' => 'value'
);
$target = array(
  'type_plate' => 'value other', 
  'type_drink' => 'value other'
);
```

What's a nice way to re-order target to match $reference order of keys and ignoring keys that are not present in $target so that the final

```
$target = array(
  'type_drink' => 'value other',
  'type_plate' => 'value other' 
);
```

Comment: I was gonna say `array_intersect_key($target, $reference)`, but then I noticed you wanted the array sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need, but here's what I interpret what you're asking for.

```
foreach($reference as $key => $val)
{
    if(isset($target[$key]))
        $tmp[$key] = $target[$key];
}
$target = $tmp;
```

Comment: I'd say `$tmp[$key] = $target[$key]`, if I'm reading his question correctly.

Comment: That seems to me what he is looking for.  Though, he may actually want `$tmp[$key] = $target[$key];`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Now that you mention it, that looks right. THe values per key are different. So I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

ksort(array_intersect_key($target, $reference));

Comment: That will sort the keys, but not in the order he wants.  Also, you can't the result of `array_intersect_key` to `ksort`.